# Swift Packages say missing but are all listed - opening project on new MacBook

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I opened my project for the first time on my new MacBook and it won't run. I am getting a bunch of errors about my packages. Github is signed in, derived data deleted, restarted, build cleaned, and package caches cleaned and resolved. Still not working.

[image]

Comment: It looks Xcode failed to download some packages. You need to resolve them again: File -> Packages -> Resolve Package Versions.

Comment: Not related to the question, but, if you go to "Report Navigator" (click the right most icon in the Navigation pane that looks like a bulleted list) you can see all the errors in a form that allows copy-paste, so you don't have to upload a photo.

Comment: If my answer was of help, I'd appreciate if you marked it as accepted via the checkmark :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors at the top tell you what's wrong:

> Failed downloading https://api.mapbox.com/...

The errors below are secondary issues that come up later. The main issue however is that you can't download the Mapbox SDK and SPM then can't resolve the package graph.

Looking at the documentation from Mapbox, I guess you haven't added the Mapbox access token to the credentials in Xcode on your new machine. (https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/guides/install/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your added packages are listed in **TARGETS -> General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content**. Otherwise, add missing dependencies using the **+** button.

[image]